# Adminer Nginx try to login but "Permission Denied"

Tags: mysql, nginx, server, centos7, adminer

So when my I already setup server and installed centOS 7.6, php 7.4.14, nginx 1.16.1, mariadb, and testing the server http://server_host_or_IP/info.php, and it worked.

After that I decided to setup **Adminer**, I put `adminer-4.7.8.php to /usr/share/nginx/html/` and
try to login using username:root & password, the respond was "session is expired please try to login again".

So I checked the info.php to check where the location of session.save_path
I commit this command:

```
chown nginx:nginx /var/lib/php/session
```

And then:

```
 sudo chmod -R 777 /var/lib/php/session
```

When I try to login using username:root & pass it says permission denied.
I even try to use:

```
sudo chmod -R 640 /var/lib/php/session
```

but its still says permission denied.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I chowned /var/lib/php/session to nginx:root and I can login.

Oddly, originally its owner and group was root:apache.